# jQuery com Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho esse código que funciona perfeitamente no Firefox, mas não consigo fazer ele funcionar no IE.

O usuário só poder escolher 10 unidades no total e quando chegar a 10 exibe um `alert()`.

Alguém tem uma ideia ou uma solução melhor?

Aqui o [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vss00f81/)

```js
function getval() {
    var inputs, index,liste;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var key in inputs) {
        var value = inputs[key].value;
        var id = inputs[key].id;
        if (value > 0) liste =liste+id+"-"+value+";";
    }

    alert(liste.replace("undefined",""));
}


function mysum() {
    var inputs, index,liste;
    nbbroca=0;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  
    for(var key in inputs) {
        var value = inputs[key].value;
        if (value > 0) nbbroca += parseInt(value);
      }

    if (nbbroca >= 10) alert(nbbroca);
}

$(":input").bind('change', function () {
    mysum();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="getval()">
        <table id="products" name="products" class="products">
            <tr class="figures">
                <th>
                    <a href="#">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/j2so2jo1b/image1.png" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">
                              <p></p>
                        </figure>
                      </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/j2so2jo1b/image1.png" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">
                            <p></p>
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/j2so2jo1b/image1.png" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">
                            <p></p>
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/j2so2jo1b/image1.png" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">
                            <p></p>
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/j2so2jo1b/image1.png" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">
                            <p></p>
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="#">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/j2so2jo1b/image1.png" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">
                            <p></p>
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="quantity">
                <td>
                    <input  id="1011" name="1011" type="number" min="0" value="0" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="1012" name="1012" type="number" min="0" value="0" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="1013" name="1013" type="number" min="0" value="0" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="1014" name="1014" type="number" min="0" value="0" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="1015" name="1015" type="number" min="0" value="0" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="1016" name="1016" type="number" min="0" value="0" >
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
</center>
```

Comment: Essa tag <meta> está a tornar o html inválido. Já experimentaste sem ela?

Comment: Não vou testar, obg

Comment: Mesmo problema !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu problema é que o `getElementsByTagName` retorna uma [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) e o `for .. in` não deve ser usado para tal, ele deve ser usado para percorrer propriedades enumeráveis de objetos.

Se mudares os teus `for...in` para `for var` isso já vai funcionar (https://jsfiddle.net/892wxwsp/). Muda o teu código para:

```
function mysum() {
    var inputs, index, liste;
    nbbroca = 0;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        var value = inputs[i].value;

        if (value > 0) nbbroca += parseInt(value);
    }
    if (nbbroca >= 10) alert(nbbroca);
}
```

Comment: Esta OK agora Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Já que você está usando `jQuery`, poderia escrever as funções usando ele, dessa forma:

```js
function sumAll() {
    var total = 0;

    $('.pra-somar').each(function() {
        var valor = parseInt(this.value);

        if (isNaN(valor)) {
            // poderia mostrar um alert('número inválido');
        } else {
            total += valor;
        }
    });

    return total;
}

function validate() {
    if(sumAll() > 10) {
        alert('A soma dos valores não pode ser maior que 10');
        // ainda pode logar os dados ou
        // guardar numa string e mostrar em um alert
        // $('.pra-somar').each(function() { console.log(this.value);});

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$(".pra-somar").bind('change', function () {
    validate();
});
```

Para cada `<input>` vocẽ precisaria adicionar a classe *`pra-somar`* e no `<form>` ficaria assim:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Você pode ler a documentação do [`jQuery.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) no site oficial do 
[`jQuery`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Vou testar, muito obrigado